# Cannot update resource when Kubernetes Ingress Controller is updated

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster (v1.14.10) which contains the kubernetes ingress controller (quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.20.0). I have the following log message at the nginx pods, when trying to update the IC to 0.30.0:

`error updating ingress rule: ingresses.networking.k8s.io "test" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress:nginx" cannot update resource "ingresses/status" in API group "networking.k8s.io" in the namespace "test"`

the clusterrolebinding and role of nginx contain the following permissions:

```
#kubectl describe clusterrolebinding nginx-role
Name:         nginx-role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  nginx-role
Subjects:
  Kind            Name   Namespace
  ----            ----   ---------
  ServiceAccount  nginx  ingress

#kubectl describe clusterrole nginx-role
Name:         nginx-role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources                           Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                           -----------------  --------------  -----
  events                              []                 []              [create patch]
  services                            []                 []              [get list update watch]
  ingresses.extensions                []                 []              [get list watch update]
  ingresses.networking.k8s.io         []                 []              [get list watch]
  namespaces                          []                 []              [get update]
  configmaps                          []                 []              [list watch get create update]
  nodes                               []                 []              [list watch get]
  endpoints                           []                 []              [list watch]
  pods                                []                 []              [list watch]
  secrets                             []                 []              [list watch]
  ingresses.extensions/status         []                 []              [update]
  ingresses.networking.k8s.io/status  []                 []              [update]
```

The ingress configuration contains the following apiVersion, which I don't know if this is the issue due to new networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 package ([4127]https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/4127)

> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress

Can you please inform me whether this is a kubernetes ingress configuration or clusterrole issue?
thank you.

Comment: Your k8s version is ancient by today's standards. I highly recommend upgrading to newer one like 1.20+

Comment: Could you share the `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` yamls by editing your question?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but just in case anyone else finds this issue when looking up the error message, I solved it by adding the `networking.k8s.io` *API group* to *ingresses/status* resources in the **nginx role** configuration.

Sample:

```
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
```

The error actually describes the issue well, it API group `"networking.k8s.io"` is missing for resource `"ingresses/status"`, you may encounter it on other resources as well, the fix is similar. As to the cause, I beleive this is a Kubernetes update issue.